# Circular bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to adjust https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/295-basic-circular-barplot/ to my needs but I don't get it.

The original code is:

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data=data.frame(
  id=seq(1,60),
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Make the plot
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar

  # This add the bars with a blue color
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("blue", 0.3)) +

  # Limits of the plot = very important. The negative value controls the size of the inner circle, the positive one is useful to add size over each bar
  ylim(-100,120) +

  # Custom the theme: no axis title and no cartesian grid
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4), "cm")     # This remove unnecessary margin around plot
  ) +

  # This makes the coordinate polar instead of cartesian.
  coord_polar(start = 0)
```

and looks like:
[image: Original]

When I change the number of entries to 360, at least this is working:

```
data=data.frame(
  id=seq(0,360),
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(0,360), sep=""),
  value=sample( seq(0,360), 361, replace=T)
)
```

[image: Number changed]

Now I want to connect these 361 entries with values from my own:

```
APD_first= c(5244, 5171, 5124, 5160, 5169, 5255, 5034, 5324, 5277, 5217, 5268, 5295, 5326, 5484, 5324, 5449, 5418, 5531, 5715, 5609, 5484, 5678, 5635, 5457, 5611, 5737, 5601, 5760, 5582, 5608, 5846, 5786, 5784, 5957, 5898, 5844, 5828, 5882, 5980, 6002, 6056, 5922, 5979, 6042, 5960, 5990, 6009, 5950, 6075, 5965, 5973, 5838, 5949, 5868, 5726, 5748, 5617, 5671, 5685, 5621, 5454, 5701, 5606, 5546, 5550, 5466, 5474, 5426, 5343, 5395, 5395, 5343, 5327, 5320, 5227, 5247, 5276, 5254, 5373, 5310, 5245, 5082, 4970, 5033, 4980, 5033, 5001, 4928, 5168, 4972, 5113, 5018, 5128, 5109, 5108, 5096, 5082, 5094, 5073, 5099, 4966, 4999, 4946, 5046, 5030, 4957, 4924, 4970, 4937, 4998, 4939, 4959, 4951, 4953, 4940, 5093, 4961, 4935, 4990, 4998, 4938, 4958, 4974, 4990, 5001, 5013, 5077, 4968, 4896, 4960, 5024, 4964, 4852, 5069, 4959, 5047, 4999, 4957, 5145, 5095, 5056, 5212, 5153, 5139, 5125, 4981, 5116, 4994, 4997, 5059, 5104, 5133, 4954, 5054, 5132, 5071, 5049, 5057, 5367, 5143, 5150, 5207, 5149, 5270, 5181, 5251 ,5160, 5180, 5231, 5277, 5227, 5259, 5275, 5127, 5200, 5206, 5252, 5250, 5211, 5343, 5330, 5438, 5402, 5389, 5426, 5534, 5431, 5592, 5650, 5630, 5680, 5669, 5664, 5696, 5643, 5862, 5674, 5923, 5721, 5804, 5890, 5925, 6021, 6075, 6075, 6058, 6128, 6723, 6244, 6099, 6202, 6086, 6240, 6245, 6122, 6257, 6102, 6068, 6176, 6311, 6311, 6154, 6331, 6212, 6238, 6231, 6237, 6181, 6187, 6176, 6167, 6119, 6319, 6321, 6298, 6318, 6380, 6306, 6330, 6413, 6330, 6435, 6377, 6419, 6503, 6561, 6426, 6376, 6311, 6461, 6440, 6466, 6393, 6435, 6503, 6403, 6390, 6361, 6444, 6319, 6278, 6235, 6313, 6238, 6282, 6344, 6255, 6311, 6208, 6236, 6194, 6284, 6287, 6362, 6281, 6332, 6237, 6345, 6203, 6422, 6409, 6365, 6383, 6439, 6440, 6383, 6298, 6374, 6450, 6356, 6450, 6343, 6326, 6357, 6427, 6470, 6366, 6296, 6160, 6408, 6227, 6173, 6156, 6261, 6043, 6282, 6209, 6136, 6147, 6106, 6113, 5998, 6006, 6002, 5894, 5877, 5847, 5825, 5784, 5825, 5840, 5819, 5826, 5806, 5837, 5715, 5749, 5765, 5553, 5598, 5614, 5519, 5547, 5658, 5635, 5577, 5454, 5410, 5524, 5432, 5388, 5342, 5390, 5563, 5281, 5240, 5283, 5257, 5158, 5097, 5220, 5148, 5192, 5133, 5203, 5176, 5238, 5123, 5210, 5126, 5234)
```

with following code modifications:

```
data=data.frame(
  id=seq(0,360),
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(0,360), sep=""),
  # value=sample( seq(0,360), 361, replace=T)
  value = APD_first
)

p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value)) +      
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("blue", 0.3)) +
    ylim(0,7000) +

    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar(start = 0)
p
```

But this looks like:

[image: Own values]

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I changed the code to:

```
# Create dataset
data=data.frame(
  id=seq(0,360),
  Angle=paste( "", seq(0,360), sep=""),
  # value=sample( seq(90,100), 361, replace=T)
   value = APD_first
)

# Make the plot
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar

  # This add the bars with a blue color
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("blue", 0.3)) +

  # Limits of the plot = very important. The negative value controls the size of the inner circle, the positive one is useful to add size over each bar
  ylim(-4000,6000) +

  # Custom the theme: no axis title and no cartesian grid
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4), "cm")     # This remove unnecessary margin around plot
  ) +

  # This makes the coordinate polar instead of cartesian.
  coord_polar(start = 0)
p
```

[image: New]

It seems I'm getting closer but I can't figure out the issue now..
Goal is to represent a circle which consists of 360 degrees. Background is that I've rotated a device in 360 degrees and measured a parameter at each degree. Now I want to visualize this.
That means I have a circular bar plot of 360 bars and each with a certain value between 4000 and 7000.

editedit: Ok..  I've mixed up the upper limit which should be 7000 instead of 6000 (as written above in the code..). That's why I ignored some bars:

[image: Final]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *connect these 361 entries with values from my own*

Comment: It looks like the problem is the `ylim` arguement. The comments from the original code you posted say " # Limits of the plot = very important. The negative value controls the size of the inner circle, the positive one is useful to add size over each bar" So I think you need to keep the -100 for the `ylim`

Comment: @PoGibas I meant there shall be 360 degrees and each degree represents a value of my own data. Finally I rotated a decive and measured a parameter at this certain degree.

Comment: Not sure how the connected plot would look like? Would a line go around the plot at y = ~5000?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik What does this mean? :)

Comment: At first thank you! This was solved faster than I thought :) Does anyone know how I can rotate the bars or respectively where is entry 0 starting? Is it at y=0 at the positive x-axis (mathematically positive)?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `coord_polar` and you will see that `start` is "the offset of starting point from 12 o'clock in radians"

Comment: @see24 yes, very obvious. Solves exactly what I'm just working on..  :D Thank you!

Comment: I recommend the [circlize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/index.html) package for that high dimensonal data.